# Java: Date from unix timestamp

Tags: java, unix, timestamp

I need to convert a unix timestamp to a date object.
I tried this:

```
java.util.Date time = new java.util.Date(timeStamp);
```

Timestamp value is: `1280512800`

The Date should be "2010/07/30 - 22:30:00" (as I get it by PHP) but instead I get `Thu Jan 15 23:11:56 IRST 1970`.

How should it be done?

Comment: If you use Java 8 or newer: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24703644/1115554

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 477, accepted):

For `1280512800`, multiply by 1000, since java is expecting milliseconds:

```
java.util.Date time=new java.util.Date((long)timeStamp*1000);
```

If you already had milliseconds, then just `new java.util.Date((long)timeStamp);`

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html):

> Allocates a Date object and
>   initializes it to represent the
>   specified number of milliseconds since
>   the standard base time known as "the
>   epoch", namely January 1, 1970,
>   00:00:00 GMT.

Comment: The cast to `(long)` is very important: without it the integer overflows.

Comment: is there a difference between Java.util.Date and Date?

Comment: @TomasK `java.util.Date` is the fully qualified name of the class. `Date` is probably the **exact same thing** provided you import the `java.util` package on your class.

Comment: The cast to long is not needed. time=new java.util.Date(timeStamp*1000L) works just as well (since 1000L is a long, timestamp will be upcast to a long before the multiplication)

Comment: I personally would do: `Date time = new Date(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(unixTimestamp, TimeUnit.SECONDS));`

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 85):

## java.time

[Java 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8_.28March_18.2C_2014.29) introduced a new API for working with dates and times: the [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html).

With java.time you can parse your count of whole seconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00Z. The result is an [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html).

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond( timeStamp );
```

If you need a `java.util.Date` to interoperate with old code not yet updated for *java.time*, convert. Call new conversion methods added to the old classes.

```
Date date = Date.from( instant );
```

Comment: While this Answer is correct technically, note that the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`. The old classes are legacy and should be avoided. While you can indeed convert to/from the legacy and java.time classes, it is best to stick with java.time whenever possible.

Answer (score 45):

This is the right way:

```
Date date = new Date ();
date.setTime((long)unix_time*1000);
```

Answer (score 38):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.ofEpochSecond( 1_280_512_800L )
```

> 2010-07-30T18:00:00Z

## java.time

The new java.time framework built into Java 8 and later is the successor to Joda-Time.

These new classes include a [handy factory method to convert a count of whole seconds](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochSecond-long-) from epoch. You get an `Instant`, a moment on the timeline in UTC with up to nanoseconds resolution.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond( 1_280_512_800L );
```

> instant.toString(): 2010-07-30T18:00:00Z

See that [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/SOI3M1).

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

### `Asia/Kabul` or `Asia/Tehran` time zones ?

You reported getting a time-of-day value of 22:30 instead of the 18:00 seen here. I suspect your PHP utility is implicitly applying a default time zone to adjust from UTC. My value here is UTC, signified by the `Z` (short for `Zulu`, means UTC). Any chance your machine OS or PHP is set to `Asia/Kabul` or [`Asia/Tehran`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asia/Tehran) time zones? I suppose so as you report `IRST` in your output which apparently means Iran time. Currently in 2017 [those are the only zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) operating with a summer time that is four and a half hours ahead of UTC.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` or `IRST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

If you *want* to see your moment through the lens of a particular region's time zone, apply a `ZoneId` to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). Still the same simultaneous moment, but seen as a different [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tehran" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );  // Same moment, same point on timeline, but seen as different wall-clock time.
```

> 2010-07-30T22:30+04:30[Asia/Tehran]

### Converting from java.time to legacy classes

You should stick with the new java.time classes. But you can convert to old if required.

```
java.util.Date date = java.util.Date.from( instant );
```

## Joda-Time

UPDATE: The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

FYI, the constructor for a [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) is similar: Multiply by a thousand to produce a `long` (not an `int`!).

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( ( 1_280_512_800L * 1000_L ), DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" ) );
```

Best to avoid the notoriously troublesome java.util.Date and .Calendar classes. But if you must use a Date, you can convert from Joda-Time.

```
java.util.Date date = dateTime.toDate();
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 26):

Looks like Calendar is the new way to go:

```
Calendar mydate = Calendar.getInstance();
mydate.setTimeInMillis(timestamp*1000);
out.println(mydate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+"."+mydate.get(Calendar.MONTH)+"."+mydate.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

The last line is just an example how to use it, this one would print eg "14.06.2012".

If you have used System.currentTimeMillis() to save the Timestamp you don't need the "*1000" part.

If you have the timestamp in a string you need to parse it first as a long: Long.parseLong(timestamp).

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: Warning: if `timestamp` is an integer you need to cast it to `(long)` first, otherwise you'll end up with wrong dates. `mydate.setTimeInMillis((long) timestamp*1000);`

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 15):

Date's constructor expects the timeStamp value to be in milliseconds.
Multiply your timestamp's value with 1000, then pass it to the constructor.

Answer (score 7):

If you are converting a timestamp value on a different machine, you should also check the timezone of that machine. For example;

The above decriptions will result different Date values, if you run with EST or UTC timezones.

To set the timezone; aka to UTC,
you can simply rewrite;

```
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    java.util.Date time= new java.util.Date((Long.parseLong(timestamp)*1000));
```

Comment: I would not recomment this because this sets the timezone for the entire jvm and not just the parsing process!

Answer (score 4):

For kotlin

```
fun unixToDate(timeStamp: Long) : String? {
    val time = java.util.Date(timeStamp as Long * 1000)
    val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
    return sdf.format(time)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

LocalDateTime is another choice, like:

```
LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochSecond(unixtime), ZoneId.systemDefault())
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to work with adjustments.

Don't use cast to long! Use nanoadjustment.

For example, using Oanda Java API for trading you can get datetime as UNIX format.

For example: 1592523410.590566943

```
    System.out.println("instant with nano = " + Instant.ofEpochSecond(1592523410, 590566943));
    System.out.println("instant = " + Instant.ofEpochSecond(1592523410));
```

you get:

```
instant with nano = 2020-06-18T23:36:50.590566943Z
instant = 2020-06-18T23:36:50Z
```

Also, use:

```
 Date date = Date.from( Instant.ofEpochSecond(1592523410, 590566943) );
```

Answer (score -4):

```
Date d = new Date(i * 1000 + TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset());
```

Comment: Without some more text, it's unclear why this answer is preferable over the many others in this question. Can you please clarify?

Comment: This will modify the date rather than converting it!