# Converting Unix timestamp to String with Joda Time

Tags: java, jodatime

When trying to convert a Unix timstamp, from a database, to a String in a date format.

```
int _startTS = evtResult.getInt("start"); //outputs 1345867200
Long _sLong = new Long(_startTS); //outputs 1345867200
//I've also tried: Long _sLong = new Long(_startTS*1000); //outputs 1542436352
DateTime _startDate = new DateTime(_sLong); //outputs 1970-01-16T08:51:07.200-05:00
```

The timestamp is for: `Sat, 25 Aug 2012`. I have no idea why 1970 is always the output so hopefully someone can see a stupid mistake I'm making.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Unix time is in seconds, Java time is milliseconds

You'll need to multiple it by 1000

```
DateTime _startDate = new DateTime(_sLong * 1000L);
```

You may want to check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371326/java-date-from-unix-timestamp) out

Comment: Edited. You should use a capital 'L' for longs. A lot more readable.

Answer (score 5):

Unix time stamp is a number of **SECONDS** since `1970-01-01 00:00:00`.

`DateTime(long instant)` constructor needs number of **MILLISECONDS**.

```
long _startTS = ((long) evtResult.getInt( "start" )) * 1000;
DateTime _startDate = new DateTime( _startTS );
```

EDIT: or use getLong(..) method on your `evtResult` to avoid the cast to long.

Comment: I know that.. I tried to multiply by 1000 but the timestamp ending up actually being 2018. I needed the `* 1000l` and everythign works great.

Answer (score 3):

When you do this: `_startTS*1000`, Java assumes you want an int because `_startTS` is an int (that's why the value is 1542436352). Try casting it as a long first:

```
Long _sLong = new Long(((long)_startTS)*1000);
```