# convert date to timestamp UTC

Tags: java, timestamp, java.util.date

I am new to Java and wanted to know how can I convert date to timestamp like

http://www.timestampconvert.com/?go1=true&m=08&d=06&y=2007&hours=05&min=30&sec=000&Submit=++++++Convert+to+timestamp+++++&offset=-5.5
if I pass a date to it and vice versa..

I searched here on StackOverflow but none of the questions have solved my problem

I need to use this timestamp in my JSON as a parameter on the highcharts API to show points

http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=msft-c.json&callback=

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Date from unix timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371326/java-date-from-unix-timestamp) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12031333/642706) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/535004/642706) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6687433/642706) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6687433/642706) and many more.

Comment: @BasilBourque thnx for you comment but i have already checked them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a date to a timestamp:

```
String date = "2014-08-03 15:20:10"; //Replace with your value
Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(date);
// Convert timestamp to long for use
long timeParameter = timestamp.getTime();
```

To convert a timestamp to a date:

```
long timeParameter = 1186358400; //Replace with your value
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(timeParameter);
Date date = new Date(timestamp.getTime());
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String textDate = df.format(date); // This gives a string like "2014-08-03 15:20:10"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Thnks for your answer buddy :)

Comment: No problem! I'm new on Stack Overflow too. Glad I could help! :)

Comment: Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(timeParameter);  here m getting like {SysUpTime = 137 days 7:26:24} {Timestamp = Sun Aug 03 20:37:33 IST 2014} how to fetch date from this like 2007-08-06 5:30:00

Answer (score -1):

```
final Date toTimestamp = new Date();
final long timestamp = toTimestamp.getTime();

final Date fromTimestamp = new Date(timestamp);
```

?

Comment: its giving output as 2014-08-03 i need 1186358400 in this format

Comment: what giving you `2014-08-03` output?