# Date to timestamp with nanos

Tags: java

I want to convert date to timestamp for setting the variable. 
I have below code but seems invalid.

```
Date org_last_upd_ts=xxxxxxx;

SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("SSSSSS");
Timestamp org_lastupdts=new Timestamp(org_last_upd_ts.getTime());
org_lastupdts.setNanos(Integer.valueOf(sdf.parse(o rg_last_upd_ts.toLocaleString()).toString()));
```

Any idea how to do so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert date to timestamp UTC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105816/convert-date-to-timestamp-utc)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String-Date conversion with nanoseconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000673/string-date-conversion-with-nanoseconds)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it like

```
java.util.Date now = new Date();
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(now.getTime());
```

From the javadoc [Timestamp constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#Timestamp-long-)

> Constructs a Timestamp object using a milliseconds time value. The integral seconds are stored in the underlying date value; the fractional seconds are stored in the nanos field of the Timestamp object.