# How to get specific date UTC value in java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am having string date in this formate (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS) how to convert this to UTC timestamp.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert date to timestamp UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105816/convert-date-to-timestamp-utc)

Comment: Convert from what time zone?

Answer (score 0):

please try like this :

```
        long time = 0;
        try {
            Date date1 = new Date((new Date()).getTime());
            SimpleDateFormat formatNowDay = new SimpleDateFormat("dd", Locale.getDefault());
            SimpleDateFormat formatNowMonth = new SimpleDateFormat("MM", Locale.getDefault());
            SimpleDateFormat formatNowHours = new SimpleDateFormat("HH", Locale.getDefault());
            SimpleDateFormat formatNowMinute = new SimpleDateFormat("mm", Locale.getDefault());
            SimpleDateFormat formatNowSecond = new SimpleDateFormat("ss", Locale.getDefault());
            SimpleDateFormat formatGMT = new SimpleDateFormat("zzz", Locale.getDefault());

            String currentDay = formatNowDay.format(date1);
            String currentMonth = formatNowMonth.format(date1);
            String currentHours = formatNowHours.format(date1);
            String currentMinute = formatNowMinute.format(date1);
            String currentSecond = formatNowSecond.format(date1);
            String GMT = formatGMT.format(date1);

            String str_date = currentDay + currentMonth + "1970" + currentHours + currentMinute + currentSecond + GMT;
            DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHHmmsszzz", Locale.getDefault());
            Date date = formatter.parse(str_date);
            time = (date.getTime() / 1000L);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return String.valueOf(time);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The format you have mentioned does not have the timezone information. Therefore, first, you should parse it to a `LocalDateTime` using a `DateTimeFormatter` and then convert this `LocalDateTime` for `ZoneOffset.UTC` to an `Instant`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // A sample date-time string
        String dateStr = "2020-02-29 19:56:36.234";
        
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.ENGLISH);     
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(dateStr, dtf);
        
        Instant instant = ldt.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        System.out.println(instant);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-02-29T19:56:36.234Z
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/tr9v0U)

An [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) represents an instantaneous point on the timeline in [UTC](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone/utc). The `Z` in the output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for a zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

**Note:** The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>. For any reason, if you need to convert this object of `Instant` to an object of `java.util.Date`, you can do so as follows:

```
Date date = Date.from(instant);
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>