# posixct date to Java date

Tags: java, date, posixct

How can I convert in `Java` a `POSIXct` date to a  formatted date like `"y-M-d"`. I've been looking around but I didn't found anything.

I read from a file these lines:

```
1398691820,517.0400,517.0400,517.0400,517.0400,56200
1398691870,517.1950,517.1950,516.8850,517.0350,2700
1398691920,516.2500,517.2050,516.2500,517.2050,5800
1398691980,515.6000,516.4408,515.6000,516.2800,7700
1398692044,515.4800,515.9700,515.4800,515.9200,5300
```

The first number of each line is a `POSIXct` date and I need to convert it to `y-M-d hour:min`.

I also have in the file the offset:

```
timezone:EDT
gmtoffset:-14400
```

Any help is very apreciated.

Thanks a lot.

**Edit:**
This the way to convert the date in R:

```r
as.POSIXct(1398691820-1400*60, origin = '1970-01-01', tz='EST')
```

Comment: Well, that sounds distinctly feasible - multiply your value by 1000 to get milliseconds since the Unix epoch, create a `Date` from that, and format with `SimpleDateFormat`. The time zone part will be "interesting" - do you have an offset per entry, or for the whole file? What have you tried so far? There's a *lot* of information about converting from a Unix timestamp to a `java.util.Date`, and a lot of information about formatting dates...

Comment: Hi, offset is for the whole file.
I'm going to try what you propose.
Thank You

Comment: it doesn't work. This posix date 1357828200 converted correctly with as.POSIXct(1357828200, origin = '1970-01-01', tz='EST') is "2013-01-10 14:30:00 EST".  
In Java I try String sfechaPosix = df.format(1398691820 * 1000) and returns 1969-12-15 01:21
i'll keep trying.

Comment: You should post your *complete* code, not just bits and pieces. Note that you should perform the multiplication using `long` arithmetic, not `int` arithemtic, otherwise you'll get overflow. (I suspect that's the issue you're seeing.) Just use `1000L` for example.

Comment: You are right. Works perfectly. I forgot to force 'long'.  My fault. Thank You very much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Date from unix timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371326/java-date-from-unix-timestamp)