# Convert Timestamp to date and hour Java

Tags: java, android, timestamp

Hi i'm getting a dates and hours in timestamp format from a webservice and i'm trying to convert them in String to show them in my app

i've tried

```
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(jsonObject.getLong("release_date"));
```

or

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");   
Date date = new Date( jsonObject.getLong("release_date"));
```

and it always give me "1970-01-17 07:54:39.6" even if i get other timestamp

for example both 1407279600 and 1406674800 give me "1970-01-17"

any idea on how to do it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Date from unix timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371326/java-date-from-unix-timestamp) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/454315/642706) and many many others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your timestamp format is probably in *seconds* since the Unix epoch, instead of the *milliseconds* that Java expects - so just multiply it by 1000:

```
Date date = new Date(jsonObject.getLong("release_date") * 1000L);
```

You should also think about what time zone you're interested in, and set that on your `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: Update for [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html): `Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond( 1_407_279_600L ) ;`  `2014-08-05T23:00:00Z`