# Converting long time to a java date

Tags: java, datetime

I get a date from a request with this format > 1413972425000

When I execute in JavaScript

> new Date(1413972425000)

the result is

> Wed Oct 22 2014 11:07:05 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)

So.. What I want is get the datetime but in Java and I don't know how can I do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Um... `new Date(1413972425000L)`? It's really unclear what you're asking for.

Comment: See the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371326/java-date-from-unix-timestamp

Comment: I was trying to parse an integer and it's a long. sorry I didn't see the other answers .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1413972425000` isn't a `int` value. It is too large for `int`. You can use it as a `long` value. `1413972425000L`

You can use

```
Date date=new Date(1413972425000L); // accept long value.
System.out.println(date);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `new Date(1413972425000L)` to convert long to date. Note the appended `L` to the numeric value.