# Convert BigInt timestamp to Date in java?

Tags: java, java.util.date

I did some searched on web about BigInt data conversion into date while I've found plenty of same question but non of them seems to work. There is 13 digit's  data **1435555326831** into my database and I think this is UNIXTIME, now I want to convert it into **yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss** form. Thank you

Comment: Which version of Java? The answer differs depending on whether you use Java 8 or another, lower version

Comment: Didn't `new Date(BigInt.longValue());` work???

Comment: FYI, classic [Unix Time](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is a count of *whole* seconds since first moment of 1970 in UTC time zone while ignoring [Leap Seconds](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second). What you have is apparently *milliseconds*. Also, be aware of other granularities. Some systems use *microseconds*, especially databases such as Postgres. The new java.time package built into Java 8 and later uses *nanoseconds*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can first convert the number into a `long` (if you receive a `BigInteger`, you can call `BigInteger.longValue()`).

Then you have two options. With the standard `java.util.Date` you can use:

```
long millis = 1435555326831L;
Date d = new Date(millis);
```

You can then format the date with a SimpleDateFormat for output.

If you can use Java 8's new Time API, you can create an instant and convert it to the desired time zone (your computer time zone in my example below):

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(millis);
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(fmt.format(instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())));
```

Note that these conversions only work if `BigInteger` is smaller than the maximum `long` size, not in general. This shouldn't be an issue, since [the maximum value of a long is `2^63 - 1`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html), but if your `BigInteger` is user input, you need to check for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is on Unix timestamp and you can simply convert it by using new java.util.Date()
and here is the example of it
[Java: Date from unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371326/java-date-from-unix-timestamp)