# Jackson Date timestamp to string

Tags: java, jackson

I am consuming an API that produces dates as Epoch timestamps but in string format:

```
{ "date":"1499762012700"}
```

Is there any way of getting this to go into a pojo as a Date object without writing some sort of custom serializer etc?

This works fine if the timestamp is a number but unfortunately this is the way it is given.

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion

Comment: Jackson can parse quoted timestamps (and any number). This `123` or this `"123"` are the same for Jackson when parsing into a Date/number in Java. What error message are you getting ? What's the configuration of your `ObjectMapper` ?

Comment: Poor question. Give exact technical details. And search Stack Overflow before posting. Explain how none of [the other 1,210 Questions and Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Jackson+date) do not address your issue.

Comment: I have seen many questions regarding the standard format such as ddMMyyyy etc, however I have not seen a numerical timestamp stored as a string before and I could not find any questions related to this.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a 9 digit timestamp? It would be helpful to have an actual example. If its unix time and do you want a java Date or a JODA object. I'd go with JODA

If its a unix 10 digit time stamp look here
[Java: Date from unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371326/java-date-from-unix-timestamp)
or