# How to parse Unix timestamp to date string in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

How can I parse a Unix timestamp to a date string in Kotlin?

For example `1532358895` to `2018-07-23T15:14:55Z`

Comment: What did you try so far? The best that comes to my mind is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371326/java-date-from-unix-timestamp

Comment: @Roland he was interested in Kotlin solution

Comment: @Roland Because that solved the problem for me, and also I wasn't aware you could call pure java libraries from Kotlin like that. However, have changed to the `java.time` method.

Comment: That's fine. Admittedly I assumed that as known... but good to know... will take that into account in future answers/comments. :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Or with the new Time API:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT
    .format(java.time.Instant.ofEpochSecond(1532358895))
```

Comment: I think this answer is much better than the one I provided. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: it just that requires API 26

Answer (score 27):

The following should work. It's just using the Java libraries for handling this:

```
    val sdf = java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
    val date = java.util.Date(1532358895 * 1000)
    sdf.format(date)
```

Comment: If you can, rather use the classes and utils of `java.time`... even though for such a simple sample it doesn't really matter...

Comment: This answer is giving me a wrong date time...The accepted answer gives me the correct date time, but it requires min API 26...