# Sunrise and sunset time are equal after converting

Tags: java, android, android-studio, unix-timestamp, openweathermap

I am trying to convert the millisecond format of time provided by openweathermap but when I convert them the times are just 1minute apart.

I have tried converting using `Simpledateformat`.

```
fun formatTIme(sun:Date):String{
    val timeformat:SimpleDateFormat= SimpleDateFormat("h:m a")
    return  timeformat.format(sun)

}

sys": {
"type": 1,
"id": 9201,
"message": 0.0075,
"country": "NP",
"sunrise": 1571444437,
"sunset": 1571485599
},
"timezone": 20700,
"id": 1282682,
"name": "Thapathali",
"cod": 200
}
```

`API call is done through Nepal` if this helps.
Why the time is just 1min difference?
Can anyone help me

Comment: How are you converting those timestamps to Dates? Also note that `m` date format character is for months, not minutes.

Comment: @laalto using https://currentmillis.com/ website

Comment: Your inputs are in seconds, not milliseconds. Multiply by 1000 for better results.

Comment: multiply by thousand worked.Thanks

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Date from unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371326/java-date-from-unix-timestamp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

I am sorry that I can write only Java code. I trust you to translate. For demonstration I am using this snippet.

```
    long sunrise = 1571444437;
    long sunset = 1571485599;
    System.out.println(formatTime(Instant.ofEpochSecond(sunrise)));
    System.out.println(formatTime(Instant.ofEpochSecond(sunset)));
```

Output is:

> ```
> 6:05 AM
> 5:31 PM
> ```

I have declared `formatTime` like this — and it works on your API level, see the details below.

```
static final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
        .ofPattern("h:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH)
        .withZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kathmandu"));

static String formatTime(Instant time) {
    return formatter.format(time);
}
```

I have specified two-digit minutes to obtain `6:05`, which is customary rather than `6:5`. If you prefer the latter, change `mm` to just `m` in the format pattern string. If you want `AM` and `PM` this way, as is customary in English, it’s a good idea to specify English locale.

Multiplying the seconds since the epoch by 1000 to obtain milliseconds, as suggested in the comments, works, but doing your own time conversions like this is a bad habit. While multiplying by 1000 seems simple, it may already leave the person reading your code wondering, and such conversions get complicated and error-prone very quickly. We have well-proven library methods to do them, which also leaves our code self-documenting: my use of the `ofEpochSecond` method already says that the number is in seconds, and there is no need for wondering, everything is clear, I think.

If you are not yet on Android API level 26 and you don’t want an external dependency, use the following for conversion:

```
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(sunrise)
```

This also tells the reader more clearly that you are doing a conversion from seconds to milliseconds.

### What went wrong in your code?

You haven’t shown the code where it goes wrong, but I think it’s clear from the comments. When treating your seconds since the epoch as milliseconds, you get `1970-01-19T10:00:44.437+05:30[Asia/Kathmandu]` for sunrise and `1970-01-19T10:01:25.599+05:30[Asia/Kathmandu]` for sunset. As you noted, there is less than a minute between them.

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.