# Unable to parse timestamp string to Calendar

Tags: java, date, calendar

I tried to convert this string "1593572400" (equivalent to GMT: Wednesday, 1 July 2020 03:00:00) to Calendar in Java. I tried parse in so many ways, but I'm always getting a java.text.parseException error.

What am I doing wrong?

```
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); // tried many other formats

try {
    date.setTime(sdf.parse(date));
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ...    
}
```

Comment: I think it might be helpful if add the entire stack trace for the exception in your question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: Date from unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371326/java-date-from-unix-timestamp). In particular, note the comments relating to `java.time` - which should be used in preference to classes such as `Date`.

Comment: The terrible `Calendar` class is obsolete, legacy, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you switch from the outdated and error-prone `java.util` date-time API to the [rich set of modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

```java
    import java.text.ParseException;
    import java.time.Instant;
    
    public class Main {
        public static void main(final String[] args) throws ParseException {
            Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(1593572400);
            System.out.println(instant);
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

```
2020-07-01T03:00:00Z
```

Once you have an object of `Instant`, you can easily convert it to other date/time objects as shown below:

```java
    import java.text.ParseException;
    import java.time.Instant;
    import java.time.LocalDateTime;
    import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
    import java.time.ZoneId;
    import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
    
    public class Main {
        public static void main(final String[] args) throws ParseException {
            Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(1593572400);
            System.out.println(instant);
    
            ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
            OffsetDateTime odt = zdt.toOffsetDateTime();
            LocalDateTime ldt = odt.toLocalDateTime();
            System.out.println(zdt);
            System.out.println(odt);
            System.out.println(ldt);
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

```
2020-07-01T03:00:00Z
2020-07-01T04:00+01:00[Europe/London]
2020-07-01T04:00+01:00
2020-07-01T04:00
```

Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html) to get an overview of modern date-time classes.

Comment: Thanks, but I have to use Calendar...unfortunatelly

Comment: @aseolin - In that case, please follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11205142/10819573).