# Simple date format giving wrong time

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, epoch

I have a time in milliseconds: `1618274313`.

When I convert it to time using this website: https://www.epochconverter.com/, I am getting `6:08:33 AM`.

But when I use `SimpleDateFormat`, I am getting something different:

```java
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date(1618274313)));
```

I am getting output as `23:01:14`.

What is the issue in my code?

Comment: Please don't use `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`, they're outdated and troublesome. [Read here why](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442/507738). Use classes from the `java.time` package instead.

Comment: Possibly related: [Java: Date from unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371326/java-date-from-unix-timestamp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, you are using time `1618274313` and you are assuming that it is in **milliseconds**. However, when I entered the same time on https://www.epochconverter.com/, I got below results:

[image]

Please notice the site mentions: `Assuming that this timestamp is in seconds`.

---

Now if we use that number multiplied by `1000` (`1618274313000`) as the input so that the site considers it in **milliseconds**, we get below results:

[image]

Please notice the site now mentions: `Assuming that this timestamp is in milliseconds`.

---

Now, when you will use `1618274313000` (correct time in milliseconds) in Java with `SimpleDateFormat`, you should get your expected result (instead of `23:01:14`):

```java
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date(1618274313000)));
```

Answer (score 2):

use Instant.ofEpochSecond

```
long test_timestamp = 1618274313L;
        LocalDateTime triggerTime =
                LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochSecond(test_timestamp), 
                                        TimeZone.getDefault().toZoneId());  

        System.out.println(triggerTime);
```

it prints output as **2021-04-13T06:08:33**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is in milliseconds as you say, all  you know for certain is that you have a specific duration.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofMillis(1618274313);
System.out.println(d);
```

Prints

```
PT449H31M14.313S
```

Which says it is 449 hours, 31 minutes and 14.313 seconds of duration.  Without knowing the epoch of this duration and any applicable zone offsets, it is not really possible to ascertain the specific date/time it represents. I could make lots of assumptions and provide results based on that, but more information from you would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

As Viral Lalakia already spotted, the epoch converter that you linked to, explicitly said that it assumed that the number was seconds (not milliseconds) since the epoch. The following makes the same assumption in Java. I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata");
    
    long unixTimestamp = 1_618_274_313;
    
    Instant when = Instant.ofEpochSecond(unixTimestamp);
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = when.atZone(zone);
    
    System.out.println(dateTime);
    System.out.println(dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME));
```

Output is:

> ```
> 2021-04-13T06:08:33+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]
> 06:08:33
> ```

This agrees with the `6:08:33 AM` that you got from the converter. And the date is today’s date. A coincidence?

If the number is indeed milliseconds (which I honestly doubt), just use `Instant.ofEpochMill()` instead of `Instant.ofEpochSecond()`.

```
    Instant when = Instant.ofEpochMilli(unixTimestamp);
```

> ```
> 1970-01-19T23:01:14.313+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]
> 23:01:14.313
> ```

This in turn agrees with the result you got in Java (except that the milliseconds are also printed).